# ValueError: can only parse strings python

Tags: python, lxml, screen-scraping

I am trying to gather a bunch of links using xpath which need to be scraped from the next page however, I keep getting the error that can only parse strings?  I tried looking at the type of lk and it was a string after I casted it?  What seems to be wrong?

```
 def unicode_to_string(types):
   try:
      types = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", types).encode('ascii', 'ignore')
      return types
  except:
      return types

def getData():
  req = "http://analytical360.com/access-points"
  page = urllib2.urlopen(req)
  tree = etree.HTML(page.read())  
  i = 0
   for lk in tree.xpath('//a[@class="sabai-file sabai-file-image sabai-file-type-jpg "]//@href'):
      print "Scraping Vendor #" + str(i)
      trees = etree.HTML(urllib2.urlopen(unicode_to_string(lk))) 
      for ll in trees.xpath('//table[@id="archived"]//tr//td//a//@href'):
         final = etree.HTML(urllib2.urlopen(unicode_to_string(ll)))
```

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?

Comment: In one part you have `page = urllib2.urlopen(req); etree.HTML(page.read())` in the next part you have `etree.HTML(urllib2.urlopen(unicode_to_string(ll)))` missing the `.read()` on the urlopen return object.

Comment: You need to pass a string not a urllib2.urlopen object to `unicode_to_string`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass in strings not urllib2.orlopen.

Perhaps change the code like so:

```
trees = etree.HTML(urllib2.urlopen(unicode_to_string(lk)).read()) 
    for i, ll in enumerate(trees.xpath('//table[@id="archived"]//tr//td//a//@href')):
        final = etree.HTML(urllib2.urlopen(unicode_to_string(ll)).read())
```

Also, you don't seem to increment `i`.